# Is there a library function in C that returns the position of first non-matching character of the two strings?

Tags: c, c-strings

I have two large strings as,

```
char str1[] = "letsgosomewhereandfindsomethingnew";
char str2[] = "letsgosomewhereandfindcomethingnew";
```

I want to get the first non-matching character of the strings, provided strings are of the same length.

Comment: I believe you are looking for strcmp.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - That doesn't return the first non-matching character though. `strcmp` returns < 0, 0, or > 0 depending on the lexicographical comparison.

Comment: Right, and the absolute value of the result is the position of the first mismatch, IIRC.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but how come this question got CV's with a reason as tool rec? This is a question about a library function (unless mentioned explicitly, that's the standard library), not a tool.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError can you elaborate? What absolute value?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError -As per my knowledge the magnitude is not the position of first mismatch,

Comment: What's the "first non-matching character" in `"aabc"` vs `"aacb"`, is it `'c'` or is it `'b'`?

Comment: @Aditya pratap singh In fact there are two mismatching characters.:) In C++ there is standard algorithm std::mismatch.:)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - nope, 0, -1, 1 are the return values

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, That doesn't seem to be the case for GNU: *The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less  than,
       to match, or be greater than s2.*

Comment: Sorry - my bad, I was referring to a specific implementation of strcmp that I've used in the past. The standard version doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight-sorry ! i want the position as there will always be two characters per mismatch

Comment: " ...provided strings are of same length."  this condition does not seem to be needed.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I am with ikegami here: MSVC man page too says `< 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError my MSVC test returns `-1`  or `1` even though the mismatch was at index `2` and even though MSVC manpage says `< 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - and yet my empirical testing of these functions in gcc (4.5.2 / sparc-sun-solaris2.11) returned only the values listed in my comment for `strcmp` asdf,asdf = 0 / asdf,bsdf = -1 / bsdf,asdf = 1 / asdf,asde = -1 / asde,asdf = 1.  So, while I wouldn't write code to test for 0,-1,1 I did find that those were the only values returned in a very small sample set. Additionally, I would never expect that an index of non-match is returned.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError how could `strcmp` return the index of the first mismatch at index `0`, when `0` indicates "matched"?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Good point. As I recall it actually returns the signed index of the first mismatch + 1 for the same reason you mention.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError empirical tests show that is not the case: nor is that documented. You might be seeing a "lazy" side-effect of an implementation that accords with the `< 0` or `> 0` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the library cstring comparisons are set up to sort. You are looking for a difference.

So in the best [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) style, roll your own:

```
char *p1 = str1;
char *p2 = str2;

while (*p1 && *p2 && (*p1 == *p2))
{
    ++p1;
    ++p2;
}
// p1 and p2 should point to the two different characters (strings match if *p1 == *p2)
```

untested on the fly coding

Or optimizing per comments made

```
char *p1 = str1;
char *p2 = str2;

while (*p1 && (*p1 == *p2))
{
    ++p1;
    ++p2;
}
// p1 and p2 should point to the two different characters (strings match if *p1 == *p2)
```

And since another comment now asks for the offset

```
int offset;

for (offset = 0; str1[offset] && (str1[offset] == str2[offset]); ++offset)
{
    // Empty block because I hate for statements without bodies
}
// Now you have the number of matching characters in offset
```

Comment: `&& *p2` can be removed; it's redundant. If p1 = "abc" and p2 = "abcd", then `*p1 && *p1 == *p2` will work (`*p1` is false).  ; If p1 = "abcd" and p2 = "abc", then `*p1 && *p1 == *p2` will work (`*p1 == *p2` is false).

Comment: Erring on the side of caution in case the strings are ever different sizes

Comment: @infixed: if they are different sizes, `*p1 == *p2` will already have been false when the end of the shorter string is reached.

Comment: I suppose `str2`'s zero terminator would stop it too.  So, ok, redundant

Comment: The comment at the end is not quite correct. They could also point at the null terminators when the two strings are equal.

Comment: Ok, re commented it

Comment: As long as we're twiddling it `while(  ( *p1 == *p2 ) && *p1)` would execute faster due to the short circuit Boolean and.  But I'm not editing the answer to save a few instruction cycles

Comment: Disagree about the certainly that `while( ( *p1 == *p2 ) && *p1)` would be faster.  It depends on the compiler and the sets of strings tested.  IAC, what you have posted is good.  Using `size_t offset;` is better